# Is the physiological progression (evolution?) of Kabane discussed in the manga?

Tags: koutetsujou-no-kabaneri

In the anime *Kabaneri of the Iron Fortress*, Kabane are shown with physical ability ranging from a [slow, zombie-like walk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTPzi.png) to a [high-speed animal-like sprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYIVh.jpg). In addition, Kabane are shown with various degrees of intelligence, ranging from mindless zombies to leader-types to being able to operate simple machinery.

What's the mechanism behind this variety? Do Kabane grow in strength, agility, and/or intelligence over time? Do their abilities depend on the original individual infected? Is it more related to the circumstances of the infection? Is there an intelligent agent and/or advanced evolutionary process behind it all?

The existence of Wazatori and Fused Colonies seems to indicate some form of guided evolution, but I'm frankly at a loss as to what mechanism could be behind all this.